# Program Counter changes

Tags: architecture, language-agnostic, hardware, program-counter

Of all possibilities in which the PC (program counter) register changes I found these:

```
1) PC increases its value with loading new instruction
2) with jumps and branches
3) with calling subroutine
4) with return from subroutine
```

Are those all or am I missing something?

I come from [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few more:

- Hardware interrupts change PC to execute interrupt service routines and then return to the interrupted program.
- Exceptional situations (exceptions like division by 0 or page fault) change PC in a similar fashion.
- Debug interrupts do that too.
- System calls (their invocation and return) change PC as well.

Comment: ..and hardware interrupts change PC to execute interrupt service routines and then return to a different program than the one that was interrupted.

Comment: @MartinJames yeah, to a program that had been interrupted. They are all interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that that is all, assuming non-local jumps are included as part of 2 (e.g. setjmp, longjmp).